# 0% fulfillment commitment for Mathematics

Tags: discussion, area-51

I know my 185 rep, 1 question and 5 answers aren't much (I guess I thought the site would be even lower level than it currently is), but apparently nobody managed to fulfill their commitment for [the Mathematics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics) at all.

Comment: I know the answer to this is going to be, "we haven't run the fulfillment script yet", but I still wanted to raise the flag. :)

Comment: Drat that gaming site, clearly you would have gained 48% fulfilled commitment if it hadn't been for them and those meddling kids! Why 6? I don't know, I just like 6.

Comment: @tim, that's not fulfilled commitment, that's percent of followers who signed up :) fulfillment is more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [faq of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#commitment) you can read that the earliest you can have fulfilled your commitment is  the start of the second day of public beta.

This is supported by the fact that yesterday around 19.00 GMT I got an email saying that I did  fulfill my commitment for the Statistical Analyses Site.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Weird, @David, because my I received the "has gone public" email for Gaming on Wed, Jul 14, 2010 at 21:02 and the "commitment fulfilled" email for Gaming on Wed, Jul 14, 2010 at 22:46.

Comment: @badp the rules changed a bit as the process went along. David is correct for *current* sites